# Should icons in a toolbar reference an action or the object?

Tags: icons, controls, toolbar

When deciding on which icon to use in a toolbar is it better for an icon to reference the action or the object?

**Example:**

Action = Export data to excel.
The object in this case is Excel (destination object).

Therefore should the icon represent 'Export' or 'Excel'.
E.g.

- Control option 1: '[Export icon] Excel'
- Control option 2: '[Excel icon] Export'

Comment: A sentence needs a noun and a verb. If you are "telling the computer to do something", that is basically a sentence, or a command. In some cases, you can get away with an *implied* noun or verb, in others, you can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Both!** Since you're not opening Excel as a software, you're making an Excel formatted file. But if this was a general action as optional exporting to a number of different output formats looking like "Export to [Excel|Text|Access|SharePoint]", I'd use just an export-icon since the next dialogue would let me make a choice of which output format to use for my exported file.

In your case I'd use an icon that represents both the action and the target, like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 both are needed for a complete representation of the function.  If just the Excel icon were shown it wouldn't be clear what the action is.  It could be import from Excel, for example.